# Teamviewer Unattended Access Not Available (Ubuntu Server 12.04)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, teamviewer

I just installed Teamviewer 8 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 via the .deb package available from the teamviewer site.

Usually to setup unattended access I pull down the connection menu and select "Setup unattendded Access" I'm sure you guys have seen this option. However, it is not present and I don't know why.

Are there any command line options to setup unattended access and if not, why isn't this option available?

Comment: Ubuntu 32 bits or 64 bits? .deb packages at Teamviewer site differs a bit, and there are some additional instalations steps for 64 bits version.